# Trying to get property of non-object: Using SELECT

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I got little problem with my code... because I try to `SELECT` sth from database and then `INSERT` some value to another table, but in normal code from [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)
and I got error

> Tryingo to get property of non-object

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    function connectionDB(){
        $host = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $db_name = "project";

        $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        return $conn;
    }
    function getID(){
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        return $id;
    }
    $login =$_SESSION['login'];
    $conn =connectionDB();
    $idCar = getID();
    echo $idCar;
    $sqluser = "SELECT ID_USER FROM login_table WHERE LOGIN = $login";

    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    $result = $conn->query($sqluser);
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO cart (id_user) VALUES ('".$row['ID_USER']."')";
        }
    }else echo"error";
?>
```

**THIS IS THE CODE OF SIDE WITH PRODUCT**

Comment: Please tell me on which line you are facing error?

Comment: The error is in line 28 $result = $conn->query($sqluser);

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\car-repair\insert.php on line 28

Comment: @MaciekWiśniewski your statement sequence is wrong. Use `$result = $conn->query($sqluser); ` before `if` loop

Comment: @MaciekWiśniewski: so what result you are getting?

Comment: @Abp Yeah i changed it but is still the same error, in line with if line `if($result->num_rows >= 0)`

Comment: Just swap the lines near your if condition...execute query before if condition

Comment: @MaciekWiśniewski: Post your exact error here

Comment: `$sqluser = "SELECT ID_USER FROM login_table WHERE LOGIN = $login";
   $result = $conn->query($sqluser);  //check result first

   if($result->num_rows > 0)  //get number of rows
   {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO cart (id_user) VALUES ('".$row['ID_USER']."')";
    }
   }else echo"error";`

still the same error in line 29

Comment: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\car-repair\insert.php on line 29
error` this is what i see when i go to my side

Comment: @MaciekWiśniewski: did you echo query and run in your database? Is it working? Have you checked it?

Comment: @Abp i can't echo query still is the same problem, and i checked it in database, its work

Answer (score 2):

Please see change near your IF loop

```
    $sqluser = "SELECT ID_USER FROM login_table WHERE LOGIN = $login";
    $result = $conn->query($sqluser);  //check result first

    if($result->num_rows > 0)  //get number of rows
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO cart (id_user) VALUES ('".$row['ID_USER']."')";
        }
    }else echo"error";
```